# WxPython custom popup window

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxwidgets

I am trying to make a custom window that acts like a popup window and closes as it loses its focus (click outside of popup).

I have a frame with several clickable images. If you click one of the images a frame appears. This frame is a base class and its contents (text controls, grids, buttons e.t.c) are replaced depending on what image you clicked. My problem is where and what event I should capture.

I will try to simplify with sample/pseudo code.

```
class MainFrame(MainFrameDefinition):
    # unimportant code
    custom_frame_holder = CustomFrame()
    for child_panel in self.lots_of_panels:
        # add a panel to a map and set
        custom_frame_holder.panel = child_panel

class CustomFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # unimportant code
        self.panel = # a panel that changes
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.lost_focus)

    def lost_focus(self, event):
        self.Hide()
```

So what seems to be the officer problem? Well as soon as I click on a control in the CustomFrame, the frame loses its focus and the window will hide.
I have tried to capture EVT_CHILD_FOCUS and then set the focus back to the frame, but then, since the frame has the focus I am unable to write in say a text control.

I have looked at the wxPopup and wxTransientPopup, but they apparently have a bug that doesn't allow radio buttons, which makes them useless to me.

Let me know if I make no sense and I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wxEVT_ACTIVATE` for this purpose (probably `wx.EVT_ACTIVATE` in `wxPython`).

I *think* the radio button issue in popup windows was fixed in the trunk.